# How to transfer iPhone contacts to Android Samsung without using iTunes?

Tags: contacts, data-transfer

For some reasons, the iPhone 4 does not talk to iTunes and I need to transfer the contacts from this to the new Samsung Android phone either Samsung Galaxy 3 or Note 2.

How can I do it?

Comment: Can you export your contact data to `.vcf` (VCard) format on your iFhone, and get that `.vcf` file to your Android device?

Comment: Does it have something like "Send contacts via Bluetooth"? or send by message? I remember my old dumb phones used to have these features. So, iphone (as a modern dumbphone) shouldn't have them?!!

Comment: Apple believes that ones you use iPhone you won't move to any other platform. I read this while I had to transfer contacts to Nokia dumb phone for one of my relative's iPhone. There are few 3rd party software that can extract contacts out from iTunes backup. So extract the contact and importing should be fairly easy.

Answer (score 9):

You can sync your contacts with gmail in iPhone, then use same email ID in android device and it will automatically sync contacts.

Comment: This is by far the simplest and best solution. If you have an Android device, you pretty much need a Google account anyway. Might as well sync the contacts to the Google account before switching phones.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a third-party tool such as copytrans contacts to export your iPhone contacts to your PC in an Android-readable format:

[image]

Also, have a look at this tutorial:

[How to transfer contacts from iPhone to Android?](http://www.copytrans.net/support/how-to-transfer-contacts-from-iphone-to-android/)

Answer (score 1):

If you can export your contacts into `.vcf` (VCard) format and transfer the export file to your Android device, no 3rd party utilities are necessary: the contacts app can directly read (and import) this file, and you are done.

If not, there's an app called [Contacts Importer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.netqin.contactbackup) available in the playstore, which claims:

> Contacts Importer is a quick and easy cross-platform solution to help you back up and import your contacts between Android, iphone, ipad, Symbian and Blackberry.

I didn't test this (and have no iWhatever), but you might give it a try and report your success here for others to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a computer to transfer contacts from Samsung mobile to iPhone5. You can follow the steps below:

1. Switch on the WiFi in both phones
2. Select contacts in Samsung
3. Select the import / export option
4. Click send name card via...
5. Select all contacts
6. Send
7. Select GMail and send to your own email ID
8. Open your GMail in iPhone
9. Open the attached contacts (v cards)
10. Add all the contacts

DONE!

Comment: Wow. Nice guide. Unfortunately, the wrong direction: OP wanted to transfer *from iPhone* and *to Samsung*. So either it's the wrong answer, or you've picked the wrong question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use a service like **Mobyko**, the syncing of contacts is done over the air. It is a trully global service that works on most phones & networks. All you need is a phone & an internet connection - let Mobyko do the rest. It is however a paid for utility

For more info:

http://www.mobyko.com/Home.do

Alternatively this free application named **Uptact** which is a contact syncing App & maybe beneficial:

http://www.uptact.com/