# Migrate contacts from iOS WITHOUT using Gmail

Tags: contacts, sync, gmail, ios

I am new to Android and have been an iOS user for a long time. I've seen a lot of tutorials to migrate my contacts from my iPhone to Android however all of them say I have to use gmail.

I take privacy very seriously and don't like the idea of have to upload all of my contact details into google's database especially after all of the leaks in the media as to how they are used.

I've never used Apple's cloud service for the same reason.

Question: How can I add my contacts from my iPhone as a flat file or perhaps via my Apple Address Book (on my mac) directly to my Android (Galaxy Nexus) WITHOUT having to give all of the data to Gmail (which I seldom use).

Thanks very much

Comment: A couple of cloud-free solutions can be found in answers to [How do I transfer iPhone contacts to an Android phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/7358/16575), [How can I transfer my contacts from an iPhone to an Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/18796/16575), and [How to transfer iPhone contacts to Android Samsung without using iTunes?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/30183/16575). Additional sources here can be obtained via an easy search for [contacts iphone](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=contacts+iphone) :)

Comment: thanks for this sorry it was so simple to answer, I googled and just came up with repetitive results about using gmail or cloud services

Comment: You don't need to apologize for an easy to answer questions :) And as a new user, you might not have known about our excellent search facility. So now you've got two answers in one (limited offer for new users :D)

Comment: Sadly no solutions there for taking contacts from my Mac or my iPhone WITHOUT some kind of disclosure to google. I adamantly do NOT want to share my address book with any kind of gmail or cloud syncing service... seems like google managed to make this impossible

Comment: Just a guess: You probably can export your contacts in VCard (`*.vcf`) format? If so, you can import that file directly into the contacts app on Android. Keep its sync off to be on the safe side, in case you cannot select the target contacts book ("Phone" wouldn't be synchronized at all).